# Finding point of svg polygon

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG object, a polygon with 3 points. I want to use javascript to rotate the polygon and add text near the point. How can I find the coordinates of the point?

```
<svg width="165" height="165" style="border: 1px solid black; ">
  <path d="M5 0   Q 80 70 160 0" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
  <path d="M5 165 Q 80 90 160 165" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>

  <polygon points="77.5,20 87.5,20 82.5,75" 
           style="fill:transparent;stroke:black;stroke-width:1"                                                   transform="rotate(90 82.5 20) " />

</svg>
```

I want to rotate the polygon to somewhere between 0 and -180 degrees from the original 90 position and add a label at the tip so the user knows how far it's been rotated.

Comment: Yes and yes to both questions.

Comment: @OvidiuDolha That's fair. I changed my question to get down to where I'm really confused.

Answer (score 0):

To rotate the polygon you can use CSS transform property e.g.

```
.svg-el {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

To animate any path or points in the polygon you manipulate it with JS, you can use a library like animejs http://animejs.com/documentation/#motionPath